# Calcular edad a partir de una fecha

Tags: angularjs-2.0, typescript

¿Cómo puedo calcular la edad a partir de una fecha?

Este es mi código, al ejecutarlo me sale `undefined` en el campo que quiero que aparezca la edad.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-6 columns">
    <label>Edad</label>
  </div>
  <div class="small-2 columns">
    <input readonly type="text" [value]="CalculateAge()">
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  DatosDTO
} from '../../dto/datos'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datos-personales',
  templateUrl: './datos-personales.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datos-personales.component.css']
})
export class DatosPersonalesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  datosDTO: DatosDTO;

  public age: number;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.datosDTO = new DatosDTO();
  }
  CalculateAge(): void {
    if (this.datosDTO.datosPersonales.fechaNacimiento) {
      var timeDiff = Math.abs(Date.now() - this.datosDTO.datosPersonales.fechaNacimiento);
      this.age = Math.ceil((timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) / 365);
    }
  }
}
```

```js
export class DatosPersona {
    tipoIdentificacion: string = "";
    numeroIdentificacion: string = "";
    nombres: string = "";
    apellidos: string = "";
    fechaNacimiento: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que el problema es que tu función `CalculateAge()` no devuelve el valor de la edad para bindearse al `input`

Una posible corrección sería

```
CalculateAge(): number {
    if (this.datosDTO.datosPersonales.fechaNacimiento) {
        var timeDiff = Math.abs(Date.now() - this.datosDTO.datosPersonales.fechaNacimiento);
        return Math.ceil((timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) / 365);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Asegúrate que la función devuelva un dato de tipo ***number*** en vez de ***void***.
2. En lugar de ***var*** utiliza ***let*** o ***const***.

> Le agregué un ***else*** para que devuelva un ***0***, con esto me aseguro de que me función siempre me regrese un número.

```
CalculateAge(): number {
    if (this.datosDTO.datosPersonales.fechaNacimiento) {
        let timeDiff = Math.abs(Date.now() - <any>this.datosDTO.datosPersonales.fechaNacimiento);
        return Math.ceil((timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) / 365);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

> Esta otra es mi propuesta el cual trabajo con objetos de tipo ***Date*** y utilizo operaciones que puedo realizar con fechas. Ademas utilizo un función ***getter*** que se encarga de devolver un dato de tipo numérico.

```
get CalculateAge(): number {
    const today: Date = new Date();
    const birthDate: Date = new Date(this.datosDTO.datosPersonales.fechaNacimiento);
    let age: number = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    const month: number = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (month < 0 || (month === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes aprovechar tu **clase DatosPersona** y crear ahí una variable calculada (una función qué es usada como una variable) que haga ése cálculo.

```
export class DatosPersona {

  tipoIdentificacion: string = "";
  numeroIdentificacion: string = "";
  nombres: string = "";
  apellidos: string = "";
  fechaNacimiento: number;
  get edad(): number {
    return ~~((Date.now() - this.fechaNacimiento || Date.now()) / (24 * 3600 * 365.25 * 1000));
  }

}
```

Luego la puedes utilizar así:

```
this.datosDTO.datosPersonales.edad
```